# only user can modify has own data in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

l want make only user  able to create new post, and only user able to modify only the post that were created by them. Like delete or edit !

database structure

```
{
  "post" : {
    "-LWzHsKzAyK9Wfa1kbD_" : {
      "name" : "test",
      "title" : "test",
      "userId" : "8D3sENaBcLaXoGNnh1MPuoyj5LP2"
    },
    "-LWzHx6u-gQ7XoVR714a" : {
      "name" : "check",
      "title" : "check",
      "userId" : "WUM2HBkGo8TFDeOjEqO1s3lCj1p1"
    }
  }
}
```

l used this rules but l got error when to save  `No such method/property 'userId'.`

```
{
    "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
        "report": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null && ( (data.exists() && data.userId === auth.uid) || !data.exists() || !newData.exists() )"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use property accessor notation to get a child value of the data. You must call the `child()` function to get the child, and the `val()` function to get its value.

So:

```
data.child('userId').val() === auth.uid
```